# Share A Post or Link on LinkedIn (HTML?)

Tags: linkedin-api

We would like to let our internal users share a post to their own LinkedIn account.

I followed the directions step-by-step from the site below:

https://tome.oauth.io/providers/linkedin/share-a-link?utm_source=coderwall&utm_medium=post&utm_content=share-post-linkedin

Their sample code works, however, when I replace their public key with mine, the linkedIn authentication box threw me an error message:

> You need to pass the "client_id" parameter

Can any of you please help?

Or can I just use their public key, will that work?

Furthermore, it seems we can only share plain text content to LinkedIn, is it possible to share HTML contents to linkedIn?

Answer (score 1):

To share a URL on LinkedIn, all you need is:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

Only the `url` parameter is supported.

For example, this works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

Works fine:

[image]

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]